# An "easy" way to get $\ln 7$ from $\ln 2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, transcendental-numbers

I was trying to convince someone that there's no "easy formula" to get $\ln 7$ from $\ln 2$ (in the sense that it is easy to get $\ln 8$ by $3\ln 2$).  I guess the formal way to state his question was whether $\ln 7$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\ln 2)$.  After some research, I now think that this is equivalent to $\ln 2$ and $\ln 7$ being algebraically independent over the rationals and that it is currently an open question whether that's the case or not.  (In other words, if someone found such an "easy" formula, that would be a major surprise.)  Is that correct or am I missing an easy proof?

Comment: See [Baker's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem).  That settles linear independence, but algebraic independence is still unknown.

Comment: Do you want the exact value or are you content with a good approximation ?

Comment: @Peter The exact value, not something like the BKM algorithm.

Comment: @lulu I guessed so.  And do I understand correctly that a proof of Schanuel's conjecture would give a negative answer to $\ln 7\in\mathbb{Q}(\ln 2)$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Schanuel's conjecture is a considerable strengthening of the Lindemann-Weierstrass-theorem. It would allow to prove , among many other things , the transcendentility of $e+\pi$ and $e\cdot \pi$. A huge class of numbers could be clarified if this conjecture could be proven. Surprisingly however is that the irrationality of $\gamma$ is not proven. I think, here Schanuel would not help.